# How to save and encode a xml string with special characters?

Tags: java, file-io

I have a string with xml content. When I save it to `File`, the results contains tags like `&lt; &quot; &gt`

How can I save such a string correctly so that encoded characters are used?

Comment: Can you please provide more information if none of the answers below are correct, or accept one of the answers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are determined to break the XML spec, then use...

http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html

The method "unescapeHtml" will do what you require.

> Unescapes a string containing entity escapes to a string containing
>   the actual Unicode characters corresponding to the escapes. Supports
>   HTML 4.0 entities.
>
> For example, the string `"&lt;Fran&ccedil;ais&gt;"` will become
>   `"<Français>"`
>
> If an entity is unrecognized, it is left alone, and inserted verbatim
>   into the result string. e.g. `"&gt;&zzzz;x"` will become `">&zzzz;x"`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.
The XML specifcation says that `<`, `&`, and `>` must be *escaped*.

Comment: Or in other words: if would encode these characters differently, the document wouldn't be valid XML anymore.